# Angular BehaviorSubject observable returns null

Tags: angular, typescript

I pass data through components using behavior subject, but when I try to get it with subscribe, it shows null even if in service it returns real value.

Code reproduction:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dok6n6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Put the code here. Links break

Comment: @AustinTFrench, I just updated link

Comment: The question should be self contained. Stackblitz is a great addition, of course. But all the info / code in question should be here as well as a detailed synopsis of the issue

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you have two instance of your service. one instance is created when inject your service and one instance is created when you use new AbstractComposeTemplateService() in AbstractComposeTemplate.
i fixed that. you can see that [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3munql?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fcompose-template%2Fabstract-compose-template.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fcompose-template%2Fabstract-compose-template-service.ts)